# Place hover or click on input type using css in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement hover on  i have successfully implement hoever on the outer li but how can I do it on `<input>` instead of `<li>`

```
ul.slides li:hover {
    border:2px solid #701344;
}



<div class="albums-div">
    <ul class="slides" style="width:148px; height:148px">

        <?php

              foreach($rings as $ring)
              {
                echo '<li> <input class="teringimage"  type="image" src="'. $ring['ringThumbNailImagePath'] .'" name="checked" value="' . $ring['id'].'" data-my-info="'. $ring['ringSetName'] .'" style="width:108px; height:108px;"></li>';
              }            
         ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: uh yes, `ul.slides input:hover`

Comment: @xFortyFourx thanks and for clicked version, i tried ul.slides li input:clicked {
    border:2px solid #701344;
} but it didn't work

Comment: there's no css pseudo class `clicked`, I'll post the answer, hold on a min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this:

```
ul.slides li input:hover {
    border:2px solid #701344;
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked hoever i am also doing clicked version, but it is not working ul.slides li input.clicked {
    border:2px solid #701344;
} any ideas?

Comment: you don't have css for clicking. You'll have to use javascript for clicking

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem? Or should it remain red even after it loses focus? In that case, you'll have to use javascript.

```
ul.slides li input:hover, ul.slides li input:focus {
 border: 2px solid #701344;
}
```

Comment: ul.slides li input.clicked {
    border:2px solid #701344;
} does make it bordered when cliked. i tried above, hover works but not after click

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Interesting, if it works, then have fun! :D (and new knowledge to me, so thanks)